# How do I append more than one child element to a parent element Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Good day everyone, I am new to programming, so I am sorry if my question looks stupid or too simple. I am trying to append 4 different child elements on a parent element.

I am building a To Do List app, and I want the app to work in such a way that when the 'task' is entered and saved, the entered task will appear on a list with a checkbox, a delete button, and an edit button. I tried appending the child elements on their parent element using .appendchild() but it's not working.

```
<Ol id="ol">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">Read a novel
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">Take a walk
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </li>
</Ol>






let inputToDoList= document.getElementById('inputToDoList');

let addButton=  document.getElementById('addButton');
let editButton= document.createElement('button');
let deleteButton= document.createElement('button');
let checkInput= document.createElement('input');

checkInput.type= "checkbox"
deleteButton.innerText= "Delete"
editButton.innerText= "Edit"


addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   let ol= document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
   let li= document.createElement('li');

   li.textContent= inputToDoList.value
   ol.appendChild(checkInput) 
   ol.appendChild(li)
   ol.appendChild(editButton)
   ol.appendChild(deleteButton)

   if(inputToDoList.value.length > 0){
      inputToDoList.value='';
}
});
```

What I want the program to do is to add inputToDoList.value, checkbox, edit button and delete button to the  each time the 'save' button is clicked on but the function only works when I click on the save button the first time. When I click on the 'save' button the subsequent times, it's only the inputToDoList.value that is added to the list. The other elements i.e. checkbox, edit button and delete button will no longer be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use **cloneNode** => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```js
// making of LI type element, with checkBox, Text and buttons Edit / delete :
const LI_toDo      = document.createElement('li')
,     chk_toDo     = document.createElement('input')
,     txt_toDo     = document.createElement('span')
,     bt_edit_toDo = document.createElement('button')
,     bt_del_toDo  = document.createElement('button')
;
chk_toDo.type            = "checkbox";
bt_edit_toDo.textContent = 'Edit';
bt_del_toDo.textContent  = 'Delete';

LI_toDo.appendChild(chk_toDo);
LI_toDo.appendChild(txt_toDo);
LI_toDo.appendChild(bt_edit_toDo);
LI_toDo.appendChild(bt_del_toDo);
// - - - - - - - - - -- - - - -- - - -making completed...

const inputToDoList = document.getElementById('inputToDoList')
,     List_ol       = document.getElementById('ol')
;

document.getElementById('addButton').onclick = function()
{
  txt_toDo.textContent  = inputToDoList.value;
  inputToDoList.value   = '';
  List_ol.appendChild( LI_toDo.cloneNode(true) );
}


List_ol.onclick = function(e)              //  clicks events over 'ol' elements
{                     
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return; // check if it is on a button

  switch (e.target.textContent)
  {
    case 'Edit':    EditButton(e.target.parentNode);    break; //  e.target.parentNode 
    case 'Delete':  DeleteButton(e.target.parentNode);  break; // === LI parent of clicked button 
  }
}

function EditButton(toDo_LI)
{
  let SpanTxt = toDo_LI.querySelector('span')
  ,   change  = prompt('Edit..',SpanTxt.textContent )
  ;
  if (change) { SpanTxt.textContent = change }
}

function DeleteButton(toDo_LI)
{
  let SpanTxt = toDo_LI.querySelector('span')
  ,   Del     = confirm(`please confirm delete of ${SpanTxt.textContent}`)
  ;
  if (Del) { List_ol.removeChild( toDo_LI ) }
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding : 0 5px 5px 0; 
  border-bottom :1px solid lightblue;
}
button { margin: 5px }
```

```html
<div>
  <label>what to do : </label><input id="inputToDoList" type="text">
  <button id="addButton">add</button>
</div>

<ol id="ol"></ol>
```

Comment: did you know how to deal with all Edit / delete button ?

Comment: I have been trying to make the edit and delete button work, but they are not working.  For the delete button, I tried to get the parent element using ```this.parentnode``` and get the child elements using ````listItem.parentNode``` and ```.removechild```. But I am not getting it. This is the code for the delete button   ``` deleteButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   let listItem= this.parentNode;
 let ul= listItem.parentNode;
   ul.removeChild(listItem);
});```

Comment: no you have to use event delegation. I will change my code to show how

Comment: I made it (prepared before) please test it

Comment: Thanks, both buttons are working well now. If you don't mind me asking, the code looks complex to me. Is there a material or documentation I can read in order to have a better understanding.

Comment: I have started with this https://javascript.info/event-delegation , but you must googlize "understanding event delegation javascript" by your self

Comment: can be is another part in my code that seems complicated for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The functions/code for the delete and add buttons are the ones looking complex

Comment: HTML does not escape the rule is a hierarchical system. Here the LI element is parent of the checkBox, the text and the 2 buttons. but all the elements LI are also children of the element OL. so to add an element we use the methods **appendChild** or the method **removeChild** . there is a appendChild in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Create the button elements inside the click event. Currently you placed the createElement outside the addButton event. As per your requirement the buttons should be created in the add click event, hence the element creation should happen inside the add click event.

```js
let inputToDoList = document.getElementById('inputToDoList');

let addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');

let ol = document.getElementById('ol');
addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let editButton = document.createElement('button');
  let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  let checkInput = document.createElement('input');
  checkInput.type = "checkbox"
  deleteButton.innerText = "Delete"
  editButton.innerText = "Edit"
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = inputToDoList.value
  ol.appendChild(checkInput)
  ol.appendChild(li)
  ol.appendChild(editButton)
  ol.appendChild(deleteButton)

  if (inputToDoList.value.length > 0) {
    inputToDoList.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputToDoList" />
<button id="addButton">
Add
</button>
<ol id="ol">

</ol>
```

Comment: @Missawi: glad it helped you to understand what's happening in your code.