# Dynamically added Item doesn't get appended the to the list

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append a list item based on the input value. However, the list item doesn't get appended. I tried to have script tags at different points, but that doesn't help. What am I missing?

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
<main>
    <div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="newtodo" id="newtodo" placeholder="New Todo...">
            <button type="submit" id="addtodo">+</button>
        </form>
        <div class="AddedTodo">
            <ul id="myList">

            </ul>
        </div>    
        <div>
            <p id="clearAll">Clear All</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Here is my JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("addtodo").onclick = function addItem() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("newtodo").value;
    var li = "<li>" + ul + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: `appendChild` expects a node (for example, created with `createElement`) for an argument, not a string.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Hey, accepted your answer. It worked. However, my understanding is so basic that I had to google a lot before I understood your code! But Thanks!

Comment: @boonie No worries :) I added links to the official documentation so you refer to them (if needed) as well . I am glad i was able to help you.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Hi, what is that function (e) in your code? What does e stand for?

Comment: `e` means the `event` In any function or (Click event) which is being called has its own events included in it. You can name it whatever you like. You put your name even like this: in the `function(boonie)` and in use `boonie.preventDefault()` and it willl still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) function to create your `li` to do `items`. and then use appendChild on that - Also consider using `addEventListener`

I have also added a functionality of `clearAll` button. Which will let you clear all to do `items` from your list.

Also, since you are using a `form` in your HTML which means the default behaviour is that it will reload the page. To stop that from happening use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var list = document.getElementById("myList")

//Add to do's
document.getElementById("addtodo").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newtodo");
  var li = document.createElement('li')
  li.textContent = inputValue.value
  list.appendChild(li)
  inputValue.value = ''
}, false);


//Clear all
document.getElementById("clearAll").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  list.innerHTML = ''
}, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="newtodo" id="newtodo" placeholder="New Todo...">
        <button type="submit" id="addtodo">+</button>
      </form>
      <div class="AddedTodo">
        <ul id="myList">

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button id="clearAll">Clear All</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy solution...

```
myList.innerHTML+='<li>'+newtodo.value+'</li>';
```

Comment: Not when you use +=

Answer (score 0):

Fist the button type should not be `submit` it should be `type="button"` and it's easy to use `innerHTML`.

```html
<body>
<main>
    <div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="newtodo" id="newtodo" placeholder="New Todo...">
            <button type="button" id="addtodo">+</button>
        </form>
        <div class="AddedTodo">
            <ul id="myList">

            </ul>
        </div>    
        <div>
            <p id="clearAll">Clear All</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

```js
document.getElementById("addtodo").onclick = function addItem() {

  const newtodo = document.getElementById("newtodo").value;

  const myList = document.getElementById("myList");

  myList.innerHTML += '<li>' + newtodo + '</li>';

}
```

Comment: @AlwaysHelping with `+=` it's going to append.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Check my `html` code, when you use `type="button"` it's not going to!

Answer (score 0):

there is many todo liste sample code here on SO...
like this one: [How do I append more than one child element to a parent element Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386279/how-do-i-append-more-than-one-child-element-to-a-parent-element-javascript/56386911#56386911)

you have  missed that any form do a submit => send data and load new page (here it relod the same page)
your button is a submit, so you have to track the submit event, not the click event of the button
...

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   myList = document.getElementById('my-list')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault() // stop the form submit ( don't let him sending data to server, don't let a page quit and loading the same one)

  let todoText =  myForm.newtodo.value.trim()  // get the todo value without spaces before / after
  if (todoText!=='')
    {
    let liTodo = document.createElement('li')
    liTodo.textContent = todoText
    myList.appendChild(liTodo)
    myForm.newtodo.value = '' // cleaner
    }
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="newtodo" placeholder="New Todo...">
  <button type="submit" >+</button>
</form>
<br>
<ul id="my-list"></ul>
```